# Is it possible to Customise paypal Business name/Company name

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to **Customise paypal Business name/Company name** which comes on top left of paypal checkout page. Actually I don't want to show my Business name in checkout page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just log in to your PayPal account, go into the profile, and then into Custom Payment Pages.  Create a new custom page profile and then you can add graphics/logos to make that checkout page look a lot nicer and say whatever you want.

The graphics used there need to be hosted on an https:// server.  If you don't have one of your own you can use [this free service](http://www.sslpic.com/) to host them for you.

Comment: Actually, you can include in the header logo in API requests, but not with Payments Standard.